# mouse down doesn't get called after inserting elements into dom using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I am trying to recreate sortable jQuery UI behavior with only jQuery:

This is the JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/606bs750/48/

Drag and drop works fine, the problem arises when I add new element into parent div.

It appears that mousedown functions aren't getting called on a newly added element.

```
$('.button').mousedown(function(e) {}); //isn't getting called
```

Why would that be so and what fix do you recommend?

Comment: The `.button` elements are added to the DOM after it loads, so you need to use a delegated event handler: `$('.parent').on('mousedown', '.button'. function(e) { ...`. Also be aware that you're duplicating the `id` attribute every time you append a new button which may cause issues in your JS code.

Comment: adding to ^^^ http://jsfiddle.net/d2g2Lspq/